# How can you get the permalink for an answer to a question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, hyperlinks, permalink

I wanted to link to an answer to a Stack Overflow question, but couldn't find a way to do it. I couldn't get the ID of the answer in order to create the link.

**How can you get the permalink for an answer to a question?**

Answer (score 24):

Beneath every answer you'll see a link called "share". That's your permalink. For example, the permalink to this answer is `http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25107/21960`.

Comment: While stated in the windows that appears when sharing a link to a question, I think it should be noted that the link includes a reference to your own account number - in this case, "21960".
This number may be removed, and the link will still function as before.

Comment: @towe right, this is very important and dangerous feature!

Comment: @Squareoot I wouldn't say it's *dangerous*. The feature exists to give you credit for bringing somebody to the platform. Anybody can create a link with anybody else's ID; the `share` link simply makes it easy to create a link that will give *me* (i.e. the authenticated user) credit.

Answer (score 17):

On any given answer, you'll see a link which says, "share". That's the permalink to the answer. Right-click it and copy the URL to your clipboard, then use that whenever you need the permalink to the answer.

```
down here!
\/
```

Comment: TXI's attempt to ruin everything: **averted**.

Comment: +1 for thwartation, but how will we handle his inevitable retaliation?

Comment: OK, I gotta ask the pony: What do mods see where my faux arrow was pointing? ;-)

Comment: Three years later, I doubt the pony will answer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/GJlnE.png