# Get the complete link with an id of a particular post

Tags: support, permalink

Is there a proper way to get the **id** of a particular answer without using the built-in `DevTools` of the browser?
Like for example, I want to refer `that` specific answer in some post, so when someone clicks the link, it will directly land them on `that` answer.

If this feature did not exist yet, I think this feature will be helpful.

Comment: Also: [How can you get the permalink for an answer to a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25106/21960)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the "share" link beneath the answer, or left-click then copy the URL from the dialog.

> [image: share link, with tool tip]
>
> [image: share link with URL and share buttons]

As you can see, the id of this answer is `259888`, or the URL `http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259888`.

Comment: o.O It is called *permalink*. All my life I, need to open first the dev tools then find the id of that answer then append it to the url **facepalm**. Thanks btw!