# What is the best way to refer to another post?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

To refer to another Stack Exchange post (in this case, my own first question), should I

- just use the question number?
- copy-paste the URL?
- other?

Comment: For getting the URL: [How can you get the permalink for an answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25106/how-can-you-get-the-permalink-for-an-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 9):

Copy-paste the URL would probably be the best -- then a person can just click the link, and see the answer for themselves.

If you want to be fancy, you can use Markdown to make words into a link, like `see [this interesting post](stackoverflow.com/12345)`.

(*For a question, pasting the link to the question auto fills the title of the post: for example, `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261678` becomes [What is the best way to refer to another post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261678)*)

If you want to be *really* fancy, you can use the "link assistant," either by clicking <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or by clicking this button over the post:

[image]

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links for more technical info on the question of *how*.

Comment: Question: from the examples above, is it accurate to infer that when inserting a link I can dispense with the slash after the question number, along with all the title verbage? (I'm sure the link assistant will be even easier, but I haven't given it a test drive yet). -- Audrey

Comment: Yes, @AudreyFisher - you just need the question ID (the number); the words after that are just to provide a friendlier, more helpful URL.

Comment: (also, note that if you are logged in and use the url from the "share" link at the bottom of the post, you could [earn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer) [some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster) [badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) for sharing links that give you credit as the referrer. Handy for sharing on Twitter or other social medium of choice!)

Comment: I'd just add that if you put the raw link in a quote bock, it will auto display the title text. `> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261678/what-is-the-best-way-to-refer-to-another-post` will render as "What is the best way to refer to another post?"

Comment: @Laura But you can't get those badges for sharing links on the SE network, right?

Comment: @Laura Were you able to find out about referrer badges within the network?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298448; TL;DR the referrer didn't work within the network before the change to https, after the change it did. That change happened in May 2017.

Comment: Re *"If you want to be fancy"*: It is not being fancy at all. It should always be like that. Don't expose naked URLs in posts in most cases.